# Kendo Custom Widget returning null instance

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Creating a custom Widget in kendo my js file looks like

```
(function(kendo, $) {
    var ui = kendo.ui,
        Widget = ui.Widget
    kendo.generateUUID = function() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        if (typeof performance !== 'undefined' && typeof performance.now === 'function') {
            d += performance.now(); //use high-precision timer if available
        }
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d / 16);
            return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
    }


    var ArcDropDownTreeView = kendo.ui.Widget.extend({
        _treeView: null,
        _uid: null,
        _dropdown: null,
        init: function(element, options) {
            var that = this;
            kendo.ui.Widget.fn.init.call(that, element, options);
            //  Widget.fn.init.call(this.element, options);

            var newDivId,
                treeElementId,
                treeElement,
                treeview,
                dropDownElementId,
                dropDownElement,
                dropdown
            uid = kendo.generateUUID();
            newDivId = ("treeDropDown{0}").replace("{0}", uid);
            treeElementId = ("treeViewElement{0}").replace("{0}", uid);
            dropDownElementId = ("dropDownElement{0}").replace("{0}", uid);
            var newDiv = $("<div></div>").prop("id", newDivId);
            dropDownElement = $("<input/>").prop("id", dropDownElementId);
            treeElement = $(element).clone().prop("id", treeElementId);
            $(newDiv).append(dropDownElement).change();
            $(newDiv).append(treeElement).change();
            $(element).append(newDiv).change();
            dropdown = $(dropDownElement).kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: [{
                    text: "",
                    value: ""
                }],
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",

            }).data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdown.bind("open", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // If the treeview is not visible, then make it visible.
                if (!$treeviewRootElem.hasClass("k-custom-visible")) {
                    $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
                        dropdown.close();
                        $treeviewRootElem.addClass("k-custom-visible");
                    });
                }
            });


            var $dropdownRootElem = $(dropDownElement).closest("span.k-dropdown");
            treeview = $(treeElement).kendoTreeView(options.treeview).data("kendoTreeView");
            treeview.bind("select", function(e) {
                // When a node is selected, display the text for the node in the dropdown and hide the treeview.
                $dropdownRootElem.find("span.k-input").text($(e.node).children("div").text());
                $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
                    $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
                });
            });
            var $treeviewRootElem = $(treeElement).closest("div.k-treeview");
            // Hide the treeview.
            var listBackgroundCss = dropdown.list.css("background-color");
            $treeviewRootElem
                .width($dropdownRootElem.width())
                .css({
                    "border": "1px solid grey",
                    "display": "none",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "background-color": listBackgroundCss,
                    "z-index": "999"
                });


            $(document).click(function(e) {
                // Ignore clicks on the treetriew.
                if ($(e.target).closest("div.k-treeview").length == 0) {
                    // If visible, then close the treeview.
                    if ($treeviewRootElem.hasClass("k-custom-visible")) {
                        $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
                            $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            that._treeView = treeview;
            that._dropdown = dropdown;
            that._uid = uid;
        },
        treeView: function() {
            console.log("Request for treeview");
            return this._treeView;
        },
        dropDown: function() {
            return this._dropdown;
        },
        dataSource: function() {
            return this.treeview.datasource;
        },
        selectElement: function(id) {
            this._treeView.select(id);

        },
        options: {
            name: "ArcDropDownTreeView"
        }
    });
    ui.plugin(ArcDropDownTreeView);


})(window.kendo, window.kendo.jQuery);
```

When I execute this code

```
var dropDownTreeView = $("#treeview").kendoArcDropDownTreeView({
    treeview: {
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Inventory/GetInventoryLocation',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: rootData(),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    name: "Name",
                    hasChildren: "hasChildren"
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
var instance = dropDownTreeView.data("ArcDropDownTreeView");
instance.selectElement(258);
```

I get a null error on instance.selectElement(258); it seems dropDownTreeView.data("ArcDropDownTreeView") is returning an undefined instance, what am I missing?.  pulling my hair out, any new widgets I create have the same behavior but all the widget frameworks are based on https://github.com/jsExtensions/kendoui-extended-api, which will run.

Comment: Is it just a typo? Try data("ArcDropDownTreeView") instead of data("ArcExtDropDownTreeView") ?

Comment: Thanks, that was among one of the many things I have been trying to get this to work.  It is very strange behavior, like I am missing a hook somewhere.

Comment: Is it perhaps a different typo?  You've called your plugin `ArcDropDownTreeView` but then call `kendoArcDropDownTreeView` to initialize it on the element.

Comment: That is correct, they append kendo to the front when you create widgets,  it initializes totally fine, renders just like it should I just cannot get a reference to the instance.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  Wouldn't the `.data()` call need to be on a jQuery object rather than on the object returned from the kendo Widget initialization method?  So you would want to get another reference to `$("#treeview")` and then call `.data(...)` on it?

Comment: with kendo widgets you get a reference to the element, then call a .data() on it to retrieve the instance of the object.  it also decorates elements with a .getKendo<WidgetName>() function to retrieve it, that is coming back undefined as well.

Comment: I am really pulling my hair out over it :)

Comment: Alright, I'll give this one more go, and then I'm out of my league.  Where you call `.data("ArcDropDownTreeView")`, should that be `.data("kendoArcDropDownTreeView")`?

Comment: :) no actually that should be correct.  (I only say that because I tried the other variation and it did not work :) ) .   according to the docs they have and the examples I have seen you drop the "kendo" when you request the instance..ugh...Thanks for the help though, always good to have a second set of eyes!

Comment: Consider that the referenced extensions API is 4 years old.  Perhaps they don't work with whatever version of Kendo UI you happen to have.  (I'm also working on a few versions back from current with Kendo, so things just don't seem to line up.)

Comment: I thought that myself,  I made sure the code matched the current DOCO on kendo's website.  its very strange that it works in one instance and not another, but then again it is progress so...LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For some reason in the code somewhere you change the element id become treeViewElement13080b8d-5b18-45ec-bb1f-254701a05b5e (that random guid)
2. Well you cant even select the element now,  how do you expect to get the reference to the widget if you cant even select the element?
3. **we can actually get the reference but with the correct id**, when
   i tried to explore it and check this out.
   [image]

furthermore youre dom looks like this now (perhaps this is causing the issue as well)

[image]

Note : you can select the widget reference using the id marked with blue line. **I know this is not the answer**, i just wanted to point out some directions in case you still want to continue your widget. i case somebody else want to help him more on this please use this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/Iwevi/2)

Comment: You are correct, I the line $(element).replaceWith(newDiv).change(); needs to be $(element).append(newDiv).change(); will update the code in the edit,  It still is not returning but that is a bug that needed to be addresses anyway, thank you so much,

Comment: The solution ended up being exactly that, replacing the replaceWith with an append allowed me to get a reference using <element>.getKendoArcDropDownTreeView();

Comment: Glad i could help. nice custom widget btw

Comment: Thanks, my first go at it.  I have not worked with Kendo since it first released.